# How can I pause my KeyManager for jumping?

Tags: java, 2d

I want to let my player jump, however currently when pressing space the player jumps endlessly. I would just like to be able to use the space key once. I think it has something to do with my getInput() method being ticked so often, I have tried pausing the thread but that hasn't worked for me.

Here's KeyManager:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{


private boolean[] keys;
public boolean up, down, left, right;
public boolean jump;

public float jumpingTime = 200;

public KeyManager(){
    keys = new boolean[256];
}

public void tick(){

    down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S] ;
    left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
    jump = keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE];
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    System.out.println("A Key was pressed");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){


    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}



}
```

and here is my player class:

```
  package com.zetcode;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

 public class Player extends Creature {


private Creature creature;

public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
    super(handler, x, y, Creature.PLAYER_WIDTH, Creature.PLAYER_HEIGHT);

    bounds.x = 16;
    bounds.y = 31;
    bounds.width = 40;
    bounds.height = 58;
}

@Override
public void tick() {
    getInput();
    move();
    handler.getGameCamera().centerOnEntity(this);

}

private void getInput(){
    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 3;
    gravity = 2;



    if(handler.getKeyManager().jump)
        yMove = -speed + -5;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().down)
        yMove = speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().left)
        xMove = -speed;
    if(handler.getKeyManager().right)
        xMove = speed;

}





@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(Assets.player, (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);

    //g.setColor(Color.RED);
    //g.fillRect((int) (x + bounds.x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
             // (int) (y + bounds.y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()),
            //  bounds.width, bounds.height);
}








}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Creature class a boolean flag isJumping. Then add it to your getInput method:

```
if (!isJumping && handler.getKeyManager().jump)
{
   //...apply your transformations for jumping
   isJumping = true;
}
```

This prevents from jumping on every keypress. But now comes the trickier part: this will (in your current code) only trigger jumping once, since the game does not know, when your character lands on the ground. So you need a collision detection between your creature and the ground.

There a some good articles on collision detection on the web and if you are using a physics engine, collision is often already included.

Let's assume you have implemented a method which is called, once your creature hits the ground, then you can add this:

```
public void creatureHitGround()
{
   //...other stuff on hit ground
   isJumping=false;
}
```

There you reset the isJumping flag which allows you to trigger a new jump.

Result: You press the key many times but only jump when you're back on the ground.